# Отправка формы с выводом сообщения

Tags: ajax, javascript, html

Отправка формы авторизации с выводом сообщения о сохранении пароля в браузере. Для этого, я полагаю - нужен submit именно?

В моем случае отправка аториз. данных происходит посредством ajax, при клике по кнопке. Есть ajaxForm - может это поможет?

Comment: Вопрос: зачем лишний функционал?

Comment: Имеется ввиду использовать встроенный в браузер функционал сохранения паролей, который к сожалению при использовании ajax уже не работает.

Comment: Вопрос2: а зачем сохранять пароль в браузере? Или что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Вопрос3: зачем нужен логин по ajax? Это бредовое использование технологии которая не для этого написана.

Comment: Имеется ввиду, что все проиходит динамически - без перезагрузки страницы: авторизация - открытие админ-панели - модерирование разделами сайта. Это ведь гараздо удобнее, + учитывая наш медленный интернет.

Разве не к этому все идет? Для чего тогда написан ajax, как Вы говорите?

Comment: Мешать все на одну страницу - не правильно тем более если у вас медленный инет. Медленный инет уже мало у кого. Ну и последнее: Ajax создан чтобы страница стала интерактивной т.е. для удобства, а не для каши как ваша задумка.

Comment: Почему же каша? Если все граматно написать, используя классы и функции, а лишнее вовремя удалять, разве это не правильно будет?

Comment: Это будет тяжеловесно и именно каша из кода. Страницы не просто так разделяют. В целом бред, но стало интересно есть ли решение проблемы такого рода.

Comment: Стоит пожертвовать одним запросом ради сохранения пароля, вряд ли это скажется на общем быстродействии взаимодействия с сайтом. Тем более что ошибки ввода вы можете обрабатывать и по ajax, а сабмит сделать только когда форма введена верно.

Comment: Кстати, вот что интересно - Firefox 4 сохраняет пароли при ajax-отправке данных без включения submit вообще. Все же остальные браузеры этого не видят.

Comment: Какая разница?! Тут система вопрос-ответ, а не почему именно так нужно человеку сейчас. Может это его ошибки, а может он изобретет что-новое в последствии. Не недооценивайте людей и идеи.

Answer (score 1):

Пароль сохраняется в броузере при сабмите формы с <input type="password". При успешном (логин и пароль правильные) ответе аякс запроса можно скриптом засабмитить форму, а скрипт уже перенаправит на нужную страницу.

Comment: Ну да, это понятно. Ну а зачем тогда ajax, если придется перенаправлять на нужную страницу? Да, я делал что-то наподобие этого, но при сабмите происходит перезагрузка страницы (js функция submit()).

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать кривой, но рабочий вариант: сделать отправку в скрытый фрейм, а при авторизации вызывать нужную функцию родительского окна. То есть, `window.parent.afterLogin()`, а в afterLogin() уже производить необходимые действия.

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте [тут](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#target").submit(function(event) {
      alert("Handler for .submit() called.");
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>


<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```